# xhtml2pdf does not render footer content if the document is over 9 pages

Tags: django, xhtml2pdf

Just hit a wall yesterday using xhtml2pdf in our django project.

As soon as a document is longer than 9 pages, the footer section in my PDF doesn't get any of its content rendered.  The footer section is rendered (I turned the border on), but no text goes in it.

I thought it may have been something to do with my content, but even just putting 9 page breaks with one word of content, the footer goes blank on all pages.

Any suggestions, I'd rather not have to go to a different library as we've used this for some time.

Calling pisa via `pisa.CreatePDF(html.encode('UTF-8'), encoding="UTF-8", dest=f, link_callback=link_callback)` for the pdf generation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, After a day of dealing with this issue, it turns out to be the page numbers causing the issue.

Once the page got to double digits, its too big for the cell its in and either pushing it down under the small footer section or not showing it because of this.